# Ingresar y mostrar fechas SQLITE Android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

Tengo 3 campos que son (código, nombre, carrera) esos campos son guardadas mediante un boton  y se guarda en una base de datos **`SQLite`**, hasta ahí todo bien, pero necesito que también tenga la fecha en que se ingresaron esos datos, ¿cómo podría hacer eso? La idea era ver si me podían ayudar a como hacer la fecha sea ingresada automáticamente sin tener que estar todo el tiempo ingresando la fecha y la hora, y después mediante otro botón en el `mainActivity` acceder a los registros, pero principalmente necesito saber ¿cómo hacer para que se ingresen las fechas y como realizar la consulta para obtener la fecha? Desde ya muchas gracias.

**Base de datos:**

```
package com.example.juan.myapplication2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String NOMBRE_BD = "prueba";
private static final int VERSION_BD = Integer.parseInt("1");
private static final String TABLA_CURSOS="CREATE TABLE CURSOS(CODIGO TEXT 
PRIMARY KEY, CURSO TEXT, CARRERA TEXT)";

public BD(Context context) {
    super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VERSION_BD);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLA_CURSOS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +TABLA_CURSOS);
        db.execSQL(TABLA_CURSOS);
}

 public void aregarcursos(String codigo, String curso, String carrera) {
    SQLiteDatabase bd=getWritableDatabase();
    if (bd!=null){
        bd.execSQL("INSERT INTO CURSOS 
 VALUES('"+codigo+"','"+curso+"','"+carrera+"')");
        bd.close();
    }

}
}
```

**Segunda Actividad:**

```
public class segundo extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText codigotxt, nombretxt, carreratxt;
Button guardar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segundo);

    codigotxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.codigotxt);
    nombretxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombretxt);
    carreratxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.carreratxt);
    guardar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.guardar);

final BD bd= new BD(getApplicationContext());
guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bd.aregarcursos(codigotxt.getText().toString(),nombretxt.getText().toString(),carreratxt.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se agrego", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma: primero declaras las columnas en el DB Helper:

```
 public static final String CURSOS_COLUMNA_CURSO = "curso";
 public static final String CURSOS_COLUMNA_FECHA = "fecha";
 ...
```

Agregas otra columna:

```
FECHA TEXT
```

Agragas este método para obtener la fecha actual:

```
private String getDate() {             // se vería así: miercoles 26/09/2018 05:30 p.m.
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm  a", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Modificas tu método agregarcursos:

```
public void aregarcursos(String codigo, String curso, String carrera) {
SQLiteDatabase bd=getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("curso", curso);
    cv.put("carrera", carrera);
    cv.put("fecha", getDate());  // aquí se inserta la fecha actual en forma automática, sin necesidad de ingresarla manualmente
    bd.insert("cursos", null, cv);
}
```

La fecha se guarda en un `string` que puedes mostrar en un `textview`:

```
 String fecha = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BD.CURSOS_COLUMNA_FECHA));
 textView.setText(fecha);
```

Por último elimina la app del emulador/dispositivo y la reinstalas con los cambios ya hechos.

Answer (score 1):

#### ¿SQLite, Como hacer la fecha sea registrada automáticamente sin tener que insertar el valor de fecha y la hora?.

Para esto puedes definir el campo de fecha de esta forma:

```
DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Por lo tanto el script para crear la tabla cambiaría, debes agregar el campo que deseas y definir el tipo `DATE`:

```
private static final String TABLA_CURSOS="CREATE TABLE CURSOS(CODIGO TEXT 
PRIMARY KEY, CURSO TEXT, CARRERA TEXT, DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

y modifica el método que realiza la inserción de datos, especificando únicamente los campos a insertar ya que el campo `DATE` automáticamente insertara el valor de la fecha:

```
 public void aregarcursos(String codigo, String curso, String carrera) {
    SQLiteDatabase bd=getWritableDatabase();

   if (bd!=null){
        bd.execSQL("INSERT INTO CURSOS(CODIGO, CURSO, CARRERA) VALUES('"+codigo+"','"+curso+"','"+carrera+"')");
        bd.close();
    }

  }
```

---

- Importante: eliminar los datos de tu aplicación o tu aplicación ya que tienes una estructura creada la cual no cambiará si la versión de tu base de datos es la misma (`VERSION_BD`).

Comment: Pero es que justamente la parte que decis que yo deberia cambiar, la del "metodo de insercion de datos" no logro comprenderla. Ya que, ¿Porque deberia modificarla si justamente la fecha se completa automaticamente? Perdon por mi ignorancia ya que soy nuevo en esto, y otra duda más "DATE" es admitido por SQLITE? Ya que buscando lei que hay que pasarlo como INT O TEXT ya que DATE no es tolerado por SQLITE. Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, que tengas un excelente dia.

Comment: Porque debes ahora especificar los campos que serán modificados " INSERT INTO CURSOS(CODIGO, CURSO, CARRERA) VALUES(..." de otra forma "INSERT INTO CURSOS VALUES(..." , tendrías que agregar la inserción de la fecha.